# Jekyll's excerpt_separator works in post's front matter but not in _config.yml

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to get post excerpts working in Jekyll. What's happening is that saying `excerpt_separator: <!--more-->` in the post's front matter works, but putting it in the _config.yml doesn't work.

Of course, I *could* do this for every post, but I'd rather get the global config working. :)

My config file:

```
baseurl: http://joycetipping.com/blog
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

This works:

```
---
layout: post
title: Test!!
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
---
Stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff.

More stuff, more stuff, more stuff, more stuff.

<!--more-->

Not in the excerpt, not in the excerpt, not in the excerpt.
```

This doesn't work:

```
---
layout: post
title: Test!!
---
Stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff.

More stuff, more stuff, more stuff, more stuff.

<!--more-->

Not in the excerpt, not in the excerpt, not in the excerpt.
```

I'm on Jekyll 3.1.2.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you generating the site with `jekyll serve`? If so, when you change `_config.yml`, you have to restart `jekyll serve`, otherwise the changes won't be applied.

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew it had to be something silly like that. I've been starting and stopping the server all day for various unrelated reasons, and so other changes to my _config.yml have been taking effect; didn't think of that at all for this problem.